# What config file specifies which services load on startup?

Tags: settings, boot

I'm using ADB and have full access to the filesystem.

I run `ps` and see a process running called `com.Something.Service`. I can `kill` the process but it restarts most of the time.

It's not a visible app, it's some kind of background service.

I want to stop it from running on startup.

I can't find the setting that causes it to run on startup. What file determines which processes like these run on startup or how can I find it?

I've tried grepping some common directories for the name of the service. I'd hope to find it in `/etc/init.d` but it's not there.

Comment: There is no configuration file to control apps/services on startup. Apps, Java services (in `system_server` process) and native services (managed by `init`), all three have different behaviors. Please narrow down the scope of your question mentioning what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable autostart on boot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209327/disable-autostart-on-boot). If it's a Google Play Services process, also see this answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216646/218526. `/etc/init/*.rc` files control native services behavior, not the processes running as virtual machines under Zygote.