# Default applications budget phone?

Tags: hardware

Is there a reason budget phones for android contain so many default applications?  Maybe this is required by Google?

I find YouTube, play books,play games, etc. to not be needed and redundant when you have a web browser especially on 16 gb phones.

Comment: I am not sure if it is a hard requirements to provide all the Google apps by default, may be it is just the cheapest was for a device manufacturer (less apps may lead to a higher price the manufacturer has to pay for the Google Android certification?). Unfortunately it seems like those details are not public (at least I wasn't able to find something on that topic on the net). Therefore I am not sure if your question can be answered.

Comment: [Android Compatibility Definition Document](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://source.android.com/compatibility/cdd&ved=2ahUKEwjEkbXpnN_tAhXSV30KHbUrChYQFjACegQIKhAD&usg=AOvVaw0eNV9I20eKk_Oqz5u8YH9Y&cshid=1608559205521) lays down **both** hardware and software requirements for **every** Android version //If you see section 2.2.3 (software) for Android 11,it **does not** list all those apps. It mentions only a few things like launcher, browser etc//IMO,they are not mandatory //*Why* included is opinion based answer

Comment: @Robert you are correct that less apps lead to a higher price the manufacturer has to pay. Also the manufacturers shipping only base GMS with their devices are treated as third class citizens by Google. Details are revealed when you apply for a contract.

Comment: @IrfanLatif do you have a source for that because that combined with beeshyams source answers the question.

Comment: @William sorry no source. Just a little exposure through someone else's experience. But anyway, your question is off-topic here in my opinion.

Comment: @beeshyams You have referenced the "Android Compatibility Definition Document", which from my understanding deals with AOSP. However the vendors do not install AOSP, instead the install Google Android which is AOSP+Google apps (and an own certification on top). It is similar to the emulators: The default images are plain Android, but there are also Google-API images.

Comment: @William helpful links from [my answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216646/218526): https://www.androidauthority.com/google-oem-licensing-345806, https://www.cetrixtablets.com/new-device-certification/

Comment: As Irfan Latif mentioned, this only applies to Google-certified devices, one reason is to include Play Store and Play Services for user convenience. On the contrary, non-Google-certified devices *cannot* have Google apps preinstalled, and they don't have Play Store and Play Services installed, among other Google apps. Compare to Chinese brands non-certified budget devices instead, they mostly don't have Google apps because Google is blocked.