# Will play services run on a dual-boot device with 2 roms once I boot into a rom without play services installed?

Tags: google-play-services, dual-boot

I have an OnePlus5 device with installed lineageOs. Because of my company's and software development needs I need to run apps that require play services. But I do not want to run all over the time.

Therefore I thought to dualboot the OnePlus 5 with the stock rom thewrefore there will be 2 roms in my device:

1. The stock one with play services where apps will run.
2. The lineageOS one that wi will use personally wiuthout playservices.

But once I boot into lineageOS would result running the playservices as well?

Comment: I am thinking to keep them seperated therefore with seperate userdata.

Comment: Typically company rules disallow custom or modified ROMs, and such a dual-boot is only possible with heavily modified ROMs.

Comment: Well in my company that's not an issue.

Comment: Your question isn't clear how you will be achieving dual boot. Simply, if the `/system/app` and `/data/app` you are booting from do not contain Play Services ([the GMS suite](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216646/218526)), they won't run. Otherwise they will.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3725636