# Why don't smartphone vendors ship without unnecessary gapps

Tags: gapps

I was wondering why smartphone vendors like OnePlus, Samsung etc ship with lot of unnecessary gapps

The user should have the independence or liberty to pick them on their own instead of getting forced and bloating the device with unwanted stuff

Like I understand PlayStore is important but for others we have alternatives. For example.

1. Google Maps alternative MapMyIndia, Apple Maps
2. Google Drive alternative Dropbox, Proton Drive etc
3. YouTube: Not everyone wants it
4. Play Games: Who needs it. When you can login with Facebook, Twitter or something else?

Actually even Playstore have alternatives like Aptoide and not everyone needs it

Comment: Because not everyone wants to care so much about making their phone apps fast or better, just convenient. They want the simplest way to fill their needs. Customer support for devices don't want to have to support everything available, so they supply the one set that costs less in money and supporting manpower. GApps fills the gaps for the customer, the device manufacturer, and the provider.

Comment: @wbogacz your reply is not convincing. The logic your gave feels more like a personal opinion

Comment: @wbogacz also I have edited the question. I asking more from bloatware point of view

Comment: What's bloatware in your opinion might not be so in every user's opinion. Mostly users prefer convenience and availability over anything else. As you are concerned only with bloatware, while in my opinion privacy is an even bigger issue. So vendors don't follow individual's desires, they address a market. But in my opinion the biggest reason behind the inclusion of Google bloatware in OEM devices is ***business***. OEMs are bound in agreements with Google. They get benefits by doing so. Also, being the core developer, Google has a monopoly in Android market.

Comment: So Google is paying vendors for bloatware? Otherwise why would oneplus or Samsung make them system apps and not uninstallable?

Comment: Google doesn't have to pay the vendors, vendors are already paying Google to get Google Play Service included in their devices. See this answer for a basic understanding: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216646/218526

Comment: Vendors don't explain to public why their product must come with X piece of bloatware or is devoid of it. In its absence, the users are left to analyze vendor's actions and device's performance and behavior to reach some sort of conclusion. Better to ask in private some ex/employee of  a vendor who might have been involved in decision making of shipping X bloat.