# How is Google Play services still running after disabling?

Tags: google, privacy, google-play-services, android-10, nokia

A while ago I disabled Google Play services, Google Play Store and lots of other Google apps in my phone.
Below is a screenshot.

[image]

[image]

One can see that Google Play services is still having cached background processes.
How can a disabled app have cached background processes?
I tried stopping the process, but keeps reincarnating.
Rebooted the device, no luck.
I was also not signed into the device with any Google account.

It's a Nokia 2.2 (Android 10). Nokia won't provide any information about rooting or modifying this device. This device is really shady.

What can I do to get rid of this?

Comment: It's because GMS is [privileged](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218153/218526) (framework and system apps). They provide [system-level services](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216646/218526) like auto-backup, cloud messaging and location provider. So they cannot be entirely disabled. OS may enable any component of an app if required by some other functionality. Unlocking bootloader, rooting the device, and uninstalling the not-required apps is the only way to get rid of this.

Comment: Google Play Services is essential for all Google apps and for a lot of apps that use Google services. Disabling it does not make sense at all if you still have apps like GMail installed.