# ❓APK components - services, activities, broadcast & content receivers where's their data Stored?

Tags: adb, security, apk, shell, system-apps

As I understand
Every `APK` install is associated with these components. Trying to figure out precisely where they are stored.

```
Services
Activities
Broadcast receivers
Content receivers
```

For most apps through third party I am able to enable and disable these

But for certain `APK` which are `/system` `APK`'s I am unable to save my settings . 
They flip back to their default settings where all the undesirable components which are actually spyware are selected

So here are my questions

-- for a specific `APK` install , how do I enlist the names of `APK` components - `services activities ,  content and broadcast receivers` using `ADB shell commands`

---what would be a switch to disable them using `ADB shell commands` & ensure my settings are saved  
---lastly  for certain `APK`'s that is `/system/priv-apps` I am unable to to save my settings. What would be the reason. Do I need to `chmod`the `octals` or `remount rw`

---where are these components stored `APK` folders .....    
`/system/app ,  /system/priv-apps , /data/app OR data folders  - /data/app`

I am attaching the screenshot of  certain components whose settings I can't save

[Appcomponent screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tv7Xw.jpg)
[image: .....Another screenshot]

Comment: You can get the information you are after by decompiling the target app's manifest (AndroidManifest.xml) and by looking into the output of `adb shell dumpsys package PKG_NAME`. Services and Activities can be disabled using `adb shell pm disable-user --user USER_ID PKG/COMPONENT_NAME`. See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/where-android-apps-store-data/218507#218507 to know where data of an app can be saved at.

Comment: Content and broadcast receivers are implemented in the app. What they do with the data you send is not specified. They can just ignore it or save it somewhere or do something else with it.

Comment: Thankyou folks. This third party tool screenshot of which I posted here successfully  checks off  all the adware broadcast receivers content activities and services for most apps. However in xiaomi phones there are system privileged apps where even if I un-check certain services activities etc. they will be checked back again. I wonder if the above   `ADB ` command's effect will be saved. It begs the question as to why that third-party tool wasn't successful in saving it's changes. Do I have to `chmod`  the APK file in spite of being   `rooted`

Comment: Android doesn't save app settings in APK files. They are merely read-only installable packages. So `chmod`ing APK file doesn't make sense at all. Disabled states are saved in `/data/system/users/<User_Id>/package-restrictions.xml`. // Disabling components of system / privileged / framework apps isn't always possible. See my comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/239374/how-is-google-play-services-still-running-after-disabling#comment317806_239374