# Google Play Services deleted, how to repair without Play Store?

Tags: installation, google-play-services

I somehow destroyed Google Play Services while clearing cache and search history because the Play Store kept hanging up indefinitely when trying to download apps. My Google account then kept pinging the phone for Play Services updates; to remedy the loop, I had to remove my Google account.

Now I can't access Play Store to attempt repair of Play Services because it requires I sign in. I try that, the phone starts the process of adding a Google account. Can't add my Google account because Play Services is gone. Catch 22.

I downloaded from Play Store a couple of "Fix Play Services" apps on a friend's phone, extracted the APK, and Bluetoothed to my Xperia. Fix Play Services says Play Services is not installed.

When posting this question, this post came up:
[Install Google Play Services without Google Play Store](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209781/install-google-play-services-without-google-play-store). This appears to be a very similar issue, a bigger problem to recover than I thought. I've never rooted a phone.

It's a Sony Xperia Z3v (D6708). Android Version 5.1.1. It is a Verizon phone, I have data and web access.

Is Play Services recoverable/reinstallable via internet? Without Play Store access?

Answer (score 1):

I once had a similar problem but in my case, it's because I tampered with the system. Have you tried downloading Play Services from an external site? If the Play Services you downloaded don't work correctly (in my case, it gave me the "force stopped" error), you need to install a new firmware which will fix all bugs.

Link to Play Services package (APK) on APK Mirror: https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services.

Use the flash stock firmware method if the above fails.

- Link to stock firmware: https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=95784891001602913
- How to flash firmware full guide: https://flash-guide.com/download-flash-official-stock-rom-sony-xperia-z3v-d6708/

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to so thoroughly answer, I appreciate you.  I'll try that tomorrow morning. Was hoping Play Services Base apk would be available somewhere.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Download [ApkPure](https://apkpure.com/apkpure/com.apkpure.aegon/download?from=aegon). Install it. Open it. Search google play services install it. Done!